# Linux permission issues: "Permission denied"

Tags: linux, postgresql, permissions

I am provisioning a postgresql server on an TinyCore64 machine and there are some files and folders that cannot be accessed by the user postgres despite the fact that I have changed the permissions, ownership and group of everything. Here are the commands and the folder structure:

```
sudo -u postgres ls /etc/ssl/
# success
# Permissions: drwxr-xr-x   6 root root

sudo -u postgres ls /etc/ssl/private
# ls: cannot open directory /etc/ssl/private/: Permission denied
# Permissions: drwxr-xr-x   2 postgres postgres
```

I am stumped. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Posted the exact transcript.

```
root@121e7b1cdaa4:~# sudo -u postgres ls -al /etc/ssl
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   6 root     root      4096 Jun 12 08:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 161 root     root      4096 Jun 12 08:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root      4096 Jun 12 08:33 certs
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root     10835 May  2 20:29 openssl.cnf
drwxr-xr-x   2 postgres postgres  4096 Jun 12 08:33 private
root@121e7b1cdaa4:~# sudo -u postgres ls -al /etc/ssl/private/
ls: cannot open directory /etc/ssl/private/: Permission denied
```

Edit:

posted the strace output:

```
root@121e7b1cdaa4:~# strace -f sudo -u postgres ls -al /etc/ssl/private/
....
[pid  4270] close(3)                    = 0
[pid  4270] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ssl/private/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid  4270] write(2, "ls: ", 4ls: )         = 4
[pid  4270] write(2, "cannot open directory /etc/ssl/p"..., 39cannot open directory /etc/ssl/private/) = 39
[pid  4270] write(2, ": Permission denied", 19: Permission denied) = 19
[pid  4270] write(2, "\n", 1
)           = 1
....
```

Comment: Can you post the exact transcript and not a version with responses as comments?

Comment: Can you run the `ls` command with `strace`? I.e. `strace -f sudo -u postgres ls -al /etc/ssl/private/` and paste the line on which you see  `Permission denied` and several lines before and after it.

Comment: Does postgres have permission to be in the directory from which you are running the command?  You are running it from root's home directory. I think that's the problem.

Comment: @user3584460 I just posted the output of strace.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I switched to the /etc/ssl directory and it still didn't work.

Comment: What are permissions of `/etc`?

Comment: @picardo I tried to reproduce your environment - both permissions and directories (I see that /etc/ is with 755) and I did not see a problem. Only the system call for me is open() and not openat(), but this should not make any difference. So, I am completely puzzled.

Comment: @user3584460 I made a mistake in my post. This is not an Ubuntu machine, but a TinyCore64 machine. (I was using a Vagrant box and zoned out on the distro.) I don't know if that makes any difference... Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I'd suspect `apparmor`. Consult your kernel log.

Comment: @DanielVérité I checked. No apparmor in this machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on "/etc/ssl" directory - it seems that 'postgres' user on your system does not have 'rx' rights somewhere on the full path to the target.

It should be smth like :

```
kaa@aknb5:~$ ls -l /etc/ |grep ssl
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Jun 13 11:00 ssl
kaa@aknb5:~$ uname -a
Linux aknb5 3.2.0-61-generic-pae #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:46:08 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
kaa@aknb5:~$
```

Comment: I double checked to make sure that it does. One thing I realized is that this machine is actually 3.13.3-tinycore64, not Ubuntu like I had originally thought. (This is a custom Vagrant box.)